# Is a ISet<T> sort of "guaranteed" to have O(1) lookup speed?

Tags: c#, performance, set, hashset

Sometimes I have a method that I want to accept a broad `IEnumerable<T>` as input, but I'm doing an operation that might have O(2^n) impact if it's not a `HashSet<T>`.

Even worse when it's a lazy `IEnumerable`.

Example:

```
public static IEnumerable<Booking> ByIds(this IEnumerable<Booking> bookings, IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    return bookings.Where(b => ids.Contains(b.Id));
}
```

- The caller could call `ToHashSet()` before calling this
  method, but I don't want the caller to think about this. For me it's
  an implementation detail.
- I could also force the input parameter to be a `HashSet`. But once
  again - I think this is an implementation detail the caller should
  not think about.
- I could also always call `ToHashSet()` in `ByIds` to be sure, but with extreme large sets this feels like unnecessary performance waste.

So I am thinking about something like the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<Booking> ByIds(this IEnumerable<Booking> bookings, IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    ids = ids.EnsureHashSet();

    return bookings.Where(b => ids.Contains(b.Id));
}

public static IEnumerable<T> EnsureHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if ( source is ISet<T> || source is IReadOnlySet<T> )
        return source;

    return source.ToHashSet();
}
```

My question is:

Is there some "intention" in the contract of a `ISet<T>` and `IReadOnlySet<T>` that it **should** be O(1) lookup performance?

I understand you can't prevent people doing weird stuff in an implementation, but if everyone is behaving properly is there at least the intention of it being a O(1) lookup?

Comment: `at least the intention of it being a O(1)` - [yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=net-7.0#remarks).

Comment: Only that's the `HashSet<T>` implementation - not the `Set<T>` interface 

Comment: Then check for HashSet... Other implementation of ISet fx SortedSet has O(log n) not O(1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no guarantee that a collection that implements the [`ISet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iset-1) interface will have an O(1) `Contains` implementation. If you want this guarantee, you should restrict the matching to types with documented O(1) behavior:

```
if (source is HashSet<T>)
```

As a side-note, the [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1) interface carries strong deferred execution semantics, and you shouldn't enumerate it more than once. There is no guarantee that enumerating an `IEnumerable<T>` multiple times will always yield the same items. Also each enumeration can be quite costly, because it might be hitting a database or a remote server. So don't do this if the `ids` is `IEnumerable<int>`:

```
return bookings.Where(b => ids.Contains(b.Id)); // Code smell
```